# Google Maps travel transit mode is not draggable

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, maps

I have the travel mode set to Driving before, it had the drag able markers in which, I could change the directions or choose an alternative route, when i did change to TRANSIT, could not do so. Are there any restrictions or any other way to achieve this (`travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.TRANSIT`)

```
 function displayRoute(origin, destination, service, display) {
            debugger;
            service.route({
                origin: { 'placeId': origin_place_id },
                destination: { 'placeId': destination_place_id },
                travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.TRANSIT,
                unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.IMPERIAL
                //travelMode: TravelMode,
                //transitOptions: TransitOptions,
                //drivingOptions: DrivingOptions
                ///avoidTolls: true
            }, function (response, status) {
                if (status === google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                    display.setDirections(response);
                } else {
                    alert('Could not display directions due to: ' + status);
                }
            });
        }
```

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the "draggable" mode is not permited to the TRANSIT travel mode. Just now I'm trying to find a way and I found your question by the way.

As the google documentation says:

> Users may modify cycling, walking or driving directions displayed
>   using a DirectionsRenderer dynamically if they are draggable, allowing
>   a user to select and alter routes by clicking and dragging the
>   resulting paths on the map. You indicate whether a renderer's display
>   allows draggable directions by setting its draggable property to true.
>   **Transit directions cannot be made draggable**.

Check it here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions#TransitOptions

We will have to find another way... if I find it I'll make you know, if you find it first I'll be grateful if you told me.